# Rest API authorization of signed and unencrypted JWT best practices

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, jwt, authorization

I just want to make sure I've got the overall idea down and don't create an implementation that violates basic security best practices. Can somebody please check my understanding?

As I understand it, a user can log in to my application and the authentication server REST API can return a JWT that is signed, but NOT encrypted. Inside that token I can have claims inside the payload that my client application can access, such as features the user can use on the application. That way my client side website can change functionality based on the user privileges and roles. The JWT claims in the payload are NOT sensitive. They will be strings representing categories for images or documents, things like that.

When the user wants to get additional content (like a document, image, or video) from other REST API endpoints, they submit the JWT along with the GET request. My API can then verify the signature of the JWT and grant API access if appropriate.

This last part is what I'm most unsure about. My intent is to use another authorization server API endpoint which takes the JWT in a POST request and returns a simple "valid/invalid" response. My thought is that my Content Delivery Network (CDN) can use this API to verify that the JWT in possession is validly signed. I believe (and maybe here is where I'm goofing up) that the authorization server API can be publicly accessible to ease use by my other microservices. This seems fine because I'm just giving a boolean pass/fail on the validity of the token so I don't see any need to hide or obfuscate the API. I question this because I know AWS has backend stuff to validate and authorize for API calls but I like the simplicity of just using REST APIs for everything for my first implementation; to maintain simplicity.

So in summary:

1.) Signed, unencrypted JWT with non-sensitive user roles/privileges.

2.) Unencrypted so client side webpage can selectively render content based on user.

3.) Public authorization API that anybody could technically use so that my CDN (and other microservices) can validate JWTs.

Any major issue with this approach? Have I committed any technical sins?

Thank you so much in advance for your time on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I've sorted this out myself after finding a great video tutorial on this stuff. Below is the video I watched:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XbXkVdoG_0

I had some misconceptions and this video sorted them out. It appears that what I described in my question is precisely how JWT should be used.